# Git Push Strange console output

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I did a git push today and I got some very strange output...
[image]

I'm using Bitbucket to host my repository, and I've never gotten output that looked like this before. **What does that ASCII art 'X' mean?**

Answer (score 0):

That's the Atlassian (Bitbucket's parent company) logo, not an X.

It's just an extra flair. A Git Server can send arbitrary text back in its response. I don't think there's a way to turn it off, unfortunately.